# Statsmodels version 0.6.1 does not include tsa?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to get the HP-filter working using `statsmodels` (sm).

The documentation [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/tsa.html) implies that the module `sm.tsa` already exists for `0.6.1`, but I get the following error:

```
>>> import statsmodels as sm
>>> sm.__version__
'0.6.1'
>>> sm.tsa.filters.hp_filter.hpfilter()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tsa'
>>> sm.tsa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tsa'
```

Here's my `pip` output:

```
nat-oitwireless-inside-vapornet100-a-14423:prog2 foobar$ pip show statsmodels
---
Name: statsmodels
Version: 0.6.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.6.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg
Requires:
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to `import statsmodels.api as sm`